# Eclipse: Stop on NotANumber

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, nan

I have a rather complex project here that involves a lot of calculations. Now I have a case where the result is `NaN`. Since a lot of classes are involved in the calculations (and NaNs tend to spread like zombies), the origin is difficult to make out.

Now I'm wondering, does anyone know of a way to make the eclipse debugger stop execution hits a `NaN`? Since Java doesn't support automatically raising an exception on `NaN`, that would be difficult, but perhaps it has be done, and I am missing it?

Thanks,
Axel

PS: I know I could add conditional breakpoints (or if-statements) on `Double.isNaN(value)`, but I would have to do so in a lot of places. (In fact that is what I am about to do right now.) Just wondering if there's a better alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now I'm wondering, does anyone know of a way to make the eclipse debugger stop execution hits a NaN?

I doubt it.

Since the normal Java behavior is to not throw exceptions when NaNs appear, the debugger would need to insert conditional breakpoints at each statement that might generate one.  That's going to be complicated to implement and expensive at runtime.  And your use-case is pretty unusual one.

I think a better approach might be to add Java assertions to your code at a few well-chosen places.

Comment: Best solution so far: adding assert !Double.isNaN(value) at different places and adding an exception breakpoint on java.lang.AssertionError comes pretty near to what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an easier way.

As an aside, the full IEEE-754 (2008) standard has an "exception handling" mechanism (which is not related to Java/C#/etc. exceptions). There are 5 exceptions:

1. Invalid operation
2. Division by zero
3. Overflow
4. Underflow
5. Inexact result

The spec also has a default exception handling strategy for each of these exceptions, which are:

1. Substitute a NaN
2. Substitute an (approriately-signed) infinity
3. Substitute an (approriately-signed) infinity
4. Ignore
5. Ignore

The standard also recommends that the user is able to override these defaults, with another exception handling strategy (several are provided), or with a custom language-specific strategy (such as throwing an Exception in Java).

Unfortunately, almost all modern languages completely ignore this part of the spec, and assume that the default exception handling strategies are "good enough".